# Pushing Into An Array MySQL Values

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to push values from a sql query into an array using array_push.
Everything works fine except one field - "Beschreibung". It's a MySQL Text Field. When I put in the row "Beschreibung" the output from the PHP is completely empty.

Here is my code so far, any help is appreciated!

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {

      
      array_push($data, array(
                "Beschreibung" => $row["Beschreibung"],
                "id" => $row["id"],
                "Titel_Veranstaltung" => $row["Titel_Veranstaltung"],
                "Strasse" => $row['Strasse'],
                "PLZ" => $row["PLZ"],
                "Ort" => $row["Ort"],
                "Bild" => $row["Bild"],
                "Telefon" => $row["Telefon"],
                "Datum" => $row["Datum"],
                "Uhrzeit" => $row["Uhrzeit"],
                "Latitude" => $row["latitude"],
                "Longitude" => $row["longitude"],
                "Teilnehmerzahl" => $row["Teilnehmerzahl"],
                "Musikrichtung" => $row["Musikrichtung"],
                "Art_Veranstaltung" => $row["Art_Veranstaltung"],
                "Dauer_Veranstaltung" => $row["Dauer_Veranstaltung"]
        ));


  }


echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please dump one row.

Comment: Add the table description to the question.

Comment: And why do you have to add the elements one by one? Any now simply add `$row` to the array?

Comment: ... because I need only certain fields

Comment: Just fetch the fields you need from the database when making the query. `SELECT field1, field2, field3, ...` and so on. Then you can also use [fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get the result as an array without the `while`-loop.

Comment: OK. Any hints why the php output is completely empty when adding the "Beschreibung" field? Is there any special treatment for the text field?

Comment: Are you sure it's empty? Try using `View Source` in the web browser to see the actual contents, without HTML rendering.

Comment: it's completely empty

Comment: There's nothing special about text columns that would cause this. Make sure the spelling and capitalization of `Beschreibung` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = [];
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it